# Yesterday's data from BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

We are having some issues pulling yesterday's Google Analytics data from BigQuery. Can anyone explain at what point a previous day's GA data is finalized?

There is some explanation here of the intraday tables, but it's not very clear:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

To get previous day data do you need to need to use the intraday tables at all? Do you have access to the fully processed dataset at 8am local time? Or is it 8 hours after the current day UTC+14:00 (etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and asked their support, this is the reply:

"According to this [Google Analytics documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092) , it states that '1 file will be exported each day that contains the previous day’s data, and 3 files will be exported each day that contain the current day's data'. In such, the minimum time that the data from Google Analytics to be exported to BigQuery was 8 hours. Although Google Analytics can be linked to BigQuery, the availability of data depends on how it was served by Google Analytics 360."

But based on experience, it's really a minimum time. Sometimes there are delays of 4-5 hours.

Comment: Google got back to me as well and said, "The daily aggregation runs on the most Western View time zone around 5-6 AM. The BigQuery export usually (though not always) occurs a few hours afterwards."

Answer (score 0):

My team has been pressing Google's support for providing SLA's for BigQuery dump, so they updated the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en):

> This feature is not governed by a service-level agreement (SLA).

In practice we are experiencing regular delays anywhere between 2 to 12 hours.